# How to stop the pointer jumping around due to the touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

When searching for solutions to cursor jumping around, I found a lot of references to touchfreeze - a package that disables the touchpad while typing. But it is no longer part of any repository that I can find. All links to it are invalid.

How can I disable the touchpad while typing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need a separate application to achieve that.

#### On 14.04

Simply run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
```

or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing false
```

to either disable or enable touchpad while typing.

#### On 15.04+

You can use [syndaemon](http://linux.die.net/man/1/syndaemon) in the background

*To add syndaemon to startup applications:*

Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && syndaemon"
```

#### Explanation

The cleanest solution is to use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
```

However, the key does not exist in versions, later than 14.04. I tested `syndaemon` on my 15.10 laptop, and it did the job perfectly.

Syndaemon has a number op options, of which the following seem the most important to me in your situation:

```
-i <idle-time>
    How many seconds to wait after the last key press before enabling the touchpad. (default is 2.0s). 
-m <poll-interval>
    How many milliseconds to wait between two polling intervals. If this value is too low, it will cause unnecessary wake-ups. If this value is too high, some key presses (press and release happen between two intervals) may not be noticed. This switch has no effect when running with -R. Default is 200ms.
```

See also [man syndaemon](http://linux.die.net/man/1/syndaemon)

Comment: Interesting. I do not have that gsettings schema.  I do have org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad, but only basic settings there. disable-while-typing not part of it.  I also have several or.gnome.settings-daemon-peripherals, such as mouse, touchscreen, etc - but touchpad is not one of them.  Must be missing more advanced drivers... Ideas?

Comment: @KateYoak it turns out the key does not exist any more in versions, later than 14.04. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

The package was removed after 10.04 (and 10.04 is no longer supported, which is why you can't find it in the repositories). From the [publishing history on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/touchfreeze/+publishinghistory):

```
Removal requested on 2010-07-28.
Deleted on 2010-07-28 by Jonathan Riddell
(From Debian) ROM; superior alternative exists, never in stable; Debian bug #587415
```

The [Debian bug report mentioned](https://bugs.debian.org/587415) says:

> Please consider removing touchfreeze from Debian:
>
> - kde-config-touchpad is far superior software with   many improvements over touchfreeze
>
>   - excellent KDE integration
>   - far more feature-full
>   - actively developed
> - touchfreeze was never in a Debian release so far

Sp, perhaps you should look into this `kde-config-touchpad`, whatever that is, if it still exists.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are excellent, but I'd just like to note that in the "Touchpad" pane of the settings screen for "Mouse and Touchpad" in 15.10, there's a tickbox that says "disable touchpad while typing" and which does what it says on the tin.

This is Cinnamon with a theme so Unity or other desktops will *look different* but I promise the button is in the same spot :)
[image]

Comment: That is not there in 16.04, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In more recent versions of Ubuntu / GNOME (where this setting has been removed from the system settings UI), you can toggle this setting with the "Disable While Typing" checkbox on the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab of **GNOME Tweaks** (`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`).

Tweaks is a useful tool for a lot of these under-the-hood configuration options (similar to the [Tweak UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweak_UI) PowerToy for Windows), and is a lot more human-friendly than `gsettings`.