# How to disable touchpad while typing in gnome?

Tags: gnome, touchpad, settings, ubuntu-gnome

I have gone through the existing answers, and none of them work for me.

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. In Ubuntu, Kubuntu, and even Xubuntu, there is an entry in Settings->Mouse to "disable touchpad while typing".

I have looked in Settings, Gnome tweak tool, and dconf-editor. None of them have any such option.

Here is the output of xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: It looks like `libinput` is used. It does not have GUI settings. But the feature is enabled by default.

Comment: @jhilmer This will work only for `xorg-synaptics`, not in `libinput`.

Comment: @jhilmer That is about Macbook, while mine is about Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: The command is `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events disabled`, or better; use syndaemon https://askubuntu.com/a/743259/72216 on 16.04 and up.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I did this and I couldn't use touch pad

Answer (score 8):

Using your terminal, enter

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing`

This will show you true, if the system is set to disable the touchpad while typing.  You can set the key with

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true`

Graphically, run `dconf_editor`, and navigate to the path org->gnome->->desktop->peripherals->touchpad and inspect the value of the key disable-while-typing

Comment: Running 'gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing' gives the output

No such key 'disable-while-typing'

Also, there is no 'disable-while-typing' option in dconf in the path you specified.

Comment: Weird - it's present in 17.04, perhaps an upgrade from 16.04?  Gsettings and dconf both fo to the same data set, they are CLI and GUI programs for getting to the settings.  I assume that you do not want to disable the touchpad entirely...